# Hide the top level menu when pop up sub menu is displayed in Android app

Tags: android, android-menu

Android app has one top level menu named "Organisation" which gets displayed on the click of ellipsis (3 dots).

On touching this menu, pop up submenu gets displayed with top item as Organisation.

> **I want to hide this top level menu**

and

> **only show 2 items in the sub pop up menu**.

"Register Org" and "Change Org" are apps 2 sub popup menu items.

How do I do that? I tried below code which doesn't work.

```
 MenuItem topLevelMenuOrganisation =      menuList.findItem(R.id.idMenuOrganisation);
    topLevelMenuOrganisation.setVisible(false);
```

> Menu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.example.jayantbhave.menuapps.MainActivity">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/idMenuOrg"
        android:title="Organisation">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/idMenuRegisterOrg"
                android:title="Register Org" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/idMenuChangeOrg"
                android:title="Change Org" />
        </menu>
    </item>
</menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the "Organisation" item from the menu. Write your menu as following:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.example.jayantbhave.menuapps.MainActivity">
<item
    android:id="@+id/idMenuRegisterOrg"
    android:title="Register Org" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/idMenuChangeOrg"
    android:title="Change Org" />
</menu>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hello Bernardo, First, I need to see "Organisation" menu on touching 3 dots at right hand top corner of app screen and then on touching organisation, another pop up menu (which I call sub pop up menu) gets displayed. My problem is this sub pop up menu contains "Organisation" as menu item  again along with "Register Org" and "Change Org" sub pop up menu items . I want to hide "Organisation" getting displayed again on sub pop up menu. Solution you suggested will simply eliminate Organisation when user first touches ellipsis (3 dots) on the title bar at the right hand top corner.